# How to change the text color in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

This should be pretty simple, but I've pored over the highcharts documentation and can't seem to find an option that specifically addresses the text color (in contrast, there are specific color options for backgrounds, borders, lines, etc.). Then I came across the [chart.style](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#chart--style) option. It *seems* like it should work -- but doesn't.

In this [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AJfPc/) you'll see that I was able to change the font-family, but not the color.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

check [this example](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked/gray), i was able to change labels colours on your jsfiddle. here's whole options parameter:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    chart: {
        style: {
            fontFamily: 'monospace',
            color: "#f00"
        }

    },
    title: {
      style: {
         color: '#F00',
         font: 'bold 16px "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif'
      }
   },
    xAxis: {
      gridLineWidth: 1,
      lineColor: '#000',
      tickColor: '#000',
      labels: {
         style: {
            color: '#F00',
            font: '11px Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif'
         }
      },
      title: {
         style: {
            color: '#333',
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            fontSize: '12px',
            fontFamily: 'Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif'

         }            
      }
   },
   yAxis: {
      minorTickInterval: 'auto',
      lineColor: '#000',
      lineWidth: 1,
      tickWidth: 1,
      tickColor: '#000',
      labels: {
         style: {
            color: '#F00',
            font: '11px Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif'
         }
      },
      title: {
         style: {
            color: '#333',
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            fontSize: '12px',
            fontFamily: 'Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif'
         }            
      }
   },
});
```

Answer (score 3):

almost every option in high charts can have style applied to it, like I have done to the y-axis in this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/h3azu/

I would also recommend going to this page,

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-dual-axes

and clicking "view options" to get an idea of other ways the 'style' option can be used to color text.

Comment: Your Fiddle doesn't work (or no longer works).  Your suggestion about clicking "View Options" helped me though!

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the highcharts.src.js you can style the individual elements for example I changed chart in your example to title and the color is picked up;

```
  title: {
    style: {
        fontFamily: 'monospace',
        color: "#f00"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Docs](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/title.style)

```
title:{
  text: 'Something',
  style: {"color": "#003C71", "fontSize": "18px"}
}
```